# Is it correct and natural to say "a shoe chafed me a blister" when I want to say that a shoe gave me a blister?

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct and natural to say *a shoe chafed me a blister* when I want to say that a shoe gave  me a blister? For example:

> My new shoes chafed me blisters.

If it is not natural, how would you say it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a shoe gave me a blister

or

> a shoe chafed me

or

> a shoe chafed me until I blistered

or

> a shoe chafed me until a blister rose

or

> a shoe chafed me raw

but something can't chafe you a noun.

Comment: _Chafe_ is not one of the (smallish) group of bitransitive verbs.